# What should be the method for solving and solution of $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\frac{x+y}{x-y}=3$

then $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2} = ?$

Comment: Let $u=x/y$, rewrite everything in terms of $u$, and solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{x+y}{x-y}=3 \implies x=2y$

$\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2} = \frac{5y^2}{3y^2}=\frac{5}{3}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint :
$$
z = \frac xy \Rightarrow \frac{z+1}{z-1} = 3
$$

$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2} = \frac{z^2+1}{z^2-1} = ?
$$

Answer (score 2):

Already many answers here...

I solved it by simply noticing, that $3=\frac 31$ and $(2+1)=3$ and $(2-1)=1$ and ${2+1\over2-1}$ is a solution and then setting $x=2,y=1$ and then $ {4+1\over4-1}=5/3$ .

(Surely, that's not a *solution* for the general case, but - let's say - always the *first step* even in the general case...)

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{As }\frac{x+y}{x-y}=\frac31$$

Applying [componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo),

$$\frac{x+y+x-y}{x+y-(x-y)}=\frac{3+1}{3-1}\implies \frac xy=2$$

$$\implies \frac{x^2}{y^2}=\frac41$$

Again, applying componendo and dividendo, $$\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2} = \frac{4+1}{4-1}=\frac53$$